# Probability Computation - Why do the results not match?

Tags: probability, hypergeometric-function, inclusion-exclusion

Say we have an urn filled with 28 white balls, 1 red and 1 black ball. The probability of getting at least one of each red and black ball (even if in this case the distinction of -at least- does not matter...), can be computed like so:

$$\sum_{r=1}^1 \left(\sum_{b=1}^1 \frac{{1 \choose r}{1 \choose b}{28 \choose 3-r-b}}{{30\choose 3}}\right)=0.00689655...$$

As I have learned by now, another (MUCH more efficient way, once more copies of colored balls are in the urn, ie. 4 red and 4 black...) of computing this, is by calculating the probability of NOT getting a red ball + NOT getting a black ball + getting only white balls and subtracting the result of this addition from 1, like so:

$$1-2(\frac{{29 \choose 3}}{{30 \choose 3}}) + \frac{{28 \choose 3}}{{30 \choose 3}}=0.00689655...$$

Now, here is where I am pulling my hair for hours, and I really hope someone can shed some light!

Let's simply replace one white ball with a yellow one in the urn (so instead of 28 we now have 27 white, 1 yellow, 1 red and 1 black ball).

$$\sum_{y=1}^1\left(\sum_{r=1}^1 \left(\sum_{b=1}^1 \frac{{1 \choose y}{1 \choose r}{1 \choose b}{27 \choose 3-y-r-b}}{{30 \choose 3}}\right)\right)=0.000246305...$$

Alright, so far, so good. Now let's try the more efficient computation method:

$$1-3(\frac{{29 \choose 3}}{{30 \choose 3}}) + \frac{{27 \choose 3}}{{30 \choose 3}}=-0.9795566$$

What? Why? Why are those results not matching? How can there be any difference between the two?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Second sentence, you want to choose three balls with the red and black included, yes? In the red/black/yellow case, you want to choose the red, black and yellow balls, yes?

Comment: @Tim Thayer Yes.

Answer (score 1):

They're not just not matching; one of them is negative, so you already know which of them is wrong.

The problem may already start where you say "the probability of not getting a red ball + not getting a black ball + getting only white balls". This is not a description of the correct [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) calculation that follows. You need to add the probabilities of not getting a red ball and not getting a white ball and then *subtract* the probability of getting only white balls, i.e. getting neither a red, nor a black ball.

It seems that because you didn't understand that what you were doing in the first case was inclusion-exclusion, you failed to apply it properly in the second case. My advice would be to read up on inclusion-exclusion, understand why what you did in the first case was correct even though you described it incorrectly, then apply it to the second case (and then reconsider whether you think that this is a "MUCH more efficient way" to solve the present problem).

Comment: I don't understand. As you can see in the example with 1 red and 1 black ball, the calculation does not subtract anything, yet the result is correct. Also, the reason I said much more efficient is, consider the urn contains 22 white balls, 4 red and 4 black. I followed and read the link, but I don't understand how this applies to my example, can you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @Jürgen: As I said, you misunderstand the calculation you performed. It does subtract. You're subtracting a probability from $1$. The first term has a minus sign, the second has a plus sign. Thus, you're forming the complement of a probability that has a plus sign on the first term and a minus sign on the second term, and not a plus sign on the second term, as in your incorrect description. This is how it should be. Please follow the link on inclusion-exclusion that I provided.

Comment: Yes I know, I am subtracting the result of $2(\frac{{29 \choose 3}}{{30 \choose 3}}) + \frac{{28 \choose 3}}{{30 \choose 3}}$ from 1. I also wrote so in my original description. Am I missing something obvious here? I can't see it if I do. You do the whole computation, and subtract the result from 1. Just like you would if it would be 1-2*(3+3). Which means, 1 minus the result of 2*(3+3) = 12. 1 -12 = -11. I even googled it: [link]https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=1-2*(3%2B3)[/link] I followed your link but I'm struggling to understand

Comment: Alright, I think I have gotten one small step closer, I realize now that it actually subtracts the result of $$2(\frac{{29 \choose 3}}{{30 \choose 3}})$$ from 1, which turns out to be a negative number, and than adds the remaining fraction $$\frac{{28 \choose 3}}{{30 \choose 3}}$$. But, knowing this, I still don't understand why the second example does not turn out to be correct. What's so different between 1 red, black and 28 white balls and 1 yellow, red, black and 27 white balls. This is so frustrating, knowing that I know nothing!

Comment: @Jürgen: If you find it difficult to follow the Wikipedia article on inclusion-exclusion, perhaps you can profit from the many questions and answers on this site under the tag [tag:inclusion-exclusion] (which I just also added to this question). Here are the [answers I've given under that tag](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=[inclusion-exclusion]+user%3A6622). What's different between your two cases is that once you have two restrictions and once you have three, so in one case you get two alternating signs and in the other you need three, but you just used two again.

Comment: Why do I need three in the other case? That makes no sense to me at all. So if I have 4 restrictions, what happens than? I'm also tired of your elitist tone, insinuating that I could benefit from thousands of randomized questions on a subject is pretty insulting to me. I have wasted 2 days trying to solve this, since nobody else seems to be willing to enlighten me, and you prefer to wrap the whole thing in an enigma surrounded by a secret, (I'm not a student doing homework, I'm just a 40 year old who figured it would be fun to do probability) I guess this is where I call it quits. Thanks!

Comment: @Jürgen: Sorry, I didn't mean to sound elitist, and you got the wrong guy regarding the homework -- I also get annoyed by people here who seem more intent on making sure they don't answer homework questions than on answering questions. I didn't want to surround something by a secret, but I also didn't want to explain inclusion-exclusion to you from scratch when there are already lots of good explanations of it out there -- I'm already spending more time on math.SE than I should be as it is :-) So I was trying to be helpful and point you to some resources...

Comment: I can see that the tagged questions may not have been very helpful, but I find the Wikipedia article rather clear, and I don't intend to replicate it here, so if you don't understand it, you're going to have to ask specific questions about things that you don't understand. I've been trying to answer whenever you asked specific questions; I'm sorry if I overlooked any.